# PowerShell String Formatting: Why is the colon character causing my variable's value to be blank?

Tags: powershell

I was looking over what's coming with the next WinRM and PowerShell 3 and I was looking through the list of breaking changes and saw something that I'd never seen before.

The example was:

```
$server = "msp42"
$status = "online"
"$server: $status"
```

The resulting output was:

> online

OK, I'd never encountered that before and have no clue why the colon caused an issue.
A solution suggested in the document was to put a space (which is silly because then you change the output):

```
"$server : $status"
```

Another suggestion was to use this format (new to me!):

```
"${server}: $status"
```

The final suggestion was to make an expression, which I am familiar with and use all the time:

```
"$($server): $status"
```

So, my questions to you PowerShell gurus out there are:

1. What the heck is up with that colon?  Does it **do** something?
2. What the heck is the `${variable}` syntax?  Is it strictly to deal with the colon or does it have some neat features?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The colon is a valid character for variable names, e.g. in `$Env:PATH`, etc.

You can use the following option, too

```
$server`: $status
```

or, for some cases a format string is more readable:

```
'{0}: {1}' -f $server, $status
```

---

Back to the colon. There is a special case for variable names that correspond to an item on a PSDrive:

```
$Env:Foo           # equivalent to the contents of Env:\Foo
$Function:C:       # equivalent to the contents of Function:\C:
${C:\autoexec.bat} # ... you get the picture
```

The syntax `${}` exists to be able to specify variable names that otherwise use characters reserved for other parts of the syntax. You could see it as being similar (but more powerful) to C#'s `@` in front of identifiers.  See above where a `\` is used in the variable name, since `$Drive:Item` only works for the current container on a drive (or the root for non-hierarchic ones like `Env`, `Alias` or `Function`).

Another example where the variable name would be normally invalid syntax:

```
PS> $+
The term '$+' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ $+
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ($+:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS> ${+} = 5
PS> ${+}
5
PS> Get-Variable +

Name                           Value
----                           -----
+                              5
```