# What is up with powershell string variable and numbers?

Tags: powershell

I have some behaviour that I can't locate documentation for, and I can't tell why this is happening:

```
PS U:\> $foo = "bar"; "baz $foo:123"
baz
```

This works as expected:

```
PS U:\> $foo = "bar"; "baz $foo"+":123"
baz bar:123
```

I'm guessing it's trying to access key in `$foo`, but it it so?

edit:

I end up using this:

```
PS U:\> $foo = "bar"; "baz ${foo}:123"
baz bar:123
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colon character is a powershell operator for drive spec, so "$foo:123" is looking for the path '123' on drive $foo.  In your second example, nothing preceeded the colon in the string ":123", so it was parsed as a literal string value.

Comment: ah, this is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386219/powershell-string-formatting-why-is-the-colon-character-causing-my-variables-v